# Excluding jars of dependency project during ant build

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar, war

am working on a java project where am using ant as build tool.

Suppose I have two projects X and Y and both are interdependent. Am looking for some thing where I can exclude some jars during the build i.e, when I build the project A it should exclude some jars during the build and while creating the war.

I know that if we want to include and exclude jars from the classpath we give

> ```
>     <include> and <exclude>
> ```

in build.xml file. But how do we do it when we want to include or exclude the jars which are outside the project.

Any help is appreciated.

I referred to the below one, but could not get any idea.
[Excluding jars from dynamically generated classpaths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451641/excluding-jars-from-dynamically-generated-classpaths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to find a solution to my question. Am posting the answer thinking it might be useful for someone in the future.
I was able to make it work using the `<exclude>`task. Below is the code snippet.

```
<target>
 <delete dir="${dest.dir}" failonerror="false" /> 
      <mkdir dir="${dest.dir}" />
  <war destfile="${package.file}" webxml="${temp.dir.web-inf}/web.xml" basedir="${temp.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${pages.dir}"/>
    <lib dir="${lib.dir}">
        <exclude name="servlet-api.jar"/>
        <include name="de.vogella.build.test.ant.jar"/>
    </lib>
    <classes dir="${temp.dir.classes}" />
  </war>
</target>
```

The reason it did not work for me in the beginning was i did not include any `<delete>` task which would delete the war file each time the project is built. So the old war file was not replaced and it was not showing me any changes. Once I included the delete it started deleting the previous build war file and updating with a new one which worked extremely fine.